# How can I the question detail page and add comments like the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, api-v2, questions, authentication, comments

Can we get the list of data when clicking on a specific question and display the question detail page like the Stack Exchange app? 
I can't find the API to get them so far, so I decided to display the link from the question/{id} API via a web view.

The problem is: how can I communicate with the web view? For example, I allow the user to login with their Stack Exchange account, so when they have logged in, I want to allow them to comment when they want on the question detail page. 
If I use the web view, how can I send the current user info and authorize that user in the web view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we get the list of data when clicking on the specific question and display the question detail page like the Stack Exchange app?

Sure: use the [/questions/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids) method and apply the appropriate [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters). The default filter doesn't return answers, comments or post contents, so you have to check a few checkboxes, e.g. `answer` → `body`, `answer` → `comments`, `comments` → `body`, `question` → `answers`, `question` → `body` and `question` → `comments`:

[image]
[image]

You can have a look at how this very question looks like [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=8676&filter=!b6AubNkUe5GPvx&site=stackapps&run=true).

> The problem is: how can I communicate with the web view? For example, I allow the user to login with their Stack Exchange account, so when they have logged in

That works (the Stack Exchange app does it too for e.g. chat, and Teams posts), but the idea is that you hand over the control to the website itself and it's (intentionally) hard to hijack that session. It's possible to inject some JavaScript in that page (I've done it to enable [AIM](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/userscripts) in a chatroom) and make e.g. a request to add a comment, just like [one of my other userscripts](https://stackapps.com/q/8122/34061) but *you wouldn't be using the API anymore*, so you're basically on your own.

> I want to allow them to comment when they want on the question detail page.

That's much easier if you do a proper [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) for a token with write access, and then a [create comment](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment) API call.

Comment: And one question. If i create my filter by clicking on edit filter. It will generate the filter link ex: filter=!9_bDDxJY5. Has it expiration time ?

Comment: No, they are *immutable and non-expiring* as per the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).